# Add quotes to string java

Tags: java, json, string, double-quotes

Trying to output some text with quotes (") like that:

```
public static String expectedFormatData(ItemRequested currentController) {
    String result = "";

    switch (currentController) {
        case ROOM: result = "{\"roomName\" : roomName, \"squareFootage\" : squareFootage"; break;
        case EQUIPMENT: result = "{\"equipmentName\" : roomName}"; break;
        case CONTROL: result = "{\"controlName\" : roomName}"; break;
        case VALUE: result = "{value}"; break;
        default: break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Output:

```
  "message": "Can't make that request. Expected data format: {\"roomName\" : roomName, \"squareFootage\" : squareFootage (com.zzheads.HomeAutomation.controller.RoomController.addRoom(RoomController.java:40))",
```

As you can see char "\" exists in string. How to insert quotes in string without that?

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use a JSON serializer.

Comment: or triple the backslashes for a quickfix.

Comment: I dont understand how Json can help?

Comment: Triple backslashes doesnt help, same output

Comment: And just for the record: are you sure that you want to look your output **exactly** like you put it up in your question? That simply looks weird.

Comment: Post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE] which will let us reproduce your problem. Also add information about required libraries/frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

A) it looks like you want to create JSON like output format. Then: use an existing library that does that for you; instead of re-inventing the wheel.

B) Consider not using an enum here. I guess you have such kind of switches over the controller type in many places by now. Or maybe not now, but you might have them soon. And that is simply: bad OO design!

What you should do instead: create an abstract class, and make each controller type a specific subclass of that. And in the end, your code just does something like

```
String controllerAsString = whatEverInstanceOfController.formatData();
```

or something along those lines.

Comment: I see some other ways I can do what I need, but how insert static string with quotes to json? Anyway I'll have to do it and anyway I'll see same result

Comment: As said; i have big troubles understanding what you want to do; and why that would be. So maybe there is a way for you to make your examples even simpler; so that we get your point.

Answer (score 0):

It's something with Json indeed, debugged code and:
before send respond as Json, respond contains string without ugly backslashes before quotes. And when I check output using Postman backslashes appears.

```
private class ApiErrorSerializer implements JsonSerializer<ApiError> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(ApiError src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
        Date date = new Date();
        result.addProperty("timestamp", String.valueOf(new Timestamp(date.getTime())));
        result.addProperty("status", String.valueOf(src.getStatus()));
        if (src.getStatus() == 404) {
            result.addProperty("error", "Not Found");
        } else {
            result.addProperty("error", "Bad Request");
        }
        result.addProperty("exception", typeOfSrc.getTypeName());

        JsonPrimitive message = new JsonPrimitive(src.getMessage());
        //result.addProperty("message", src.getMessage());
        result.add("message", message);

        result.addProperty("path", src.getPath());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Debug: when string converts to JsonPrimitive, looks like it adds backslashes before quotes.
Output:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2016-08-21 19:45:12.157",
  "status": "400",
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "com.zzheads.HomeAutomation.exceptions.ApiErrorBadRequest",
  "message": "Can't make that request. Expected data format: {\"roomName\" : roomName, \"squareFootage\" : squareFootage} (com.zzheads.HomeAutomation.controller.RoomController.addRoom(RoomController.java:40))",
  "path": "/room"
}
```

Comment: That's perfectly correct. Quotes in a JSON string are supposed to be backslash escaped. How else would you want it?

Comment: I dont want see backslashes before quotes, like usual String do. Example: System.out.printf("Some text with \"quotes\""); Output: Some text with "quotes". <- There is no backslashes

Comment: The backslashes you're seeing have nothing to do with the backslashes in the source code. They're there because backslashes need to be escaped in a JSON string, as I said. Otherwise, there's no way to know the message doesn't end at `roomName"`. Whatever you're using to read and display the message will know not to show the backslashes, so there's really no problem.